# Display input as precentage

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a html slider and an input field that sits right next to it. The input field displays the same value as the slider .01 - .99. I am wondering how to display the number in the input field as a percentage version of it, ie .99 is displayed as 99%. The code is simple but here:

```
    <div sc-slider
        ng-model="vm.baseline"
        min="0.01"
        max="0.99"
        step="0.01"></div>
    <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="vm.baseline"></input>
```

If you can link me to something else on line cool but I looked and couldn't find anything and surely can't be the only person needing to do this. I tried to do like `vm.baseline *100` but for obvious reasons that didn't work. Help if you can!

Comment: My bad, filters not allowed on ng-model.

Comment: you need  a directive that requires ngModel controller and change the `$viewValue` in link function. Should find lots of tutorials on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement custom directive that `require: ngModel` and change input/output with `$parsers | $formatters` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/FGuskyRwXCScPd1Kpd6a?p=preview

```
app.directive('toPercent', function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(value){
          return value * 100 + '%';
      });

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value){
          return parseFloat(value.replace('%', ''));
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Excellent. You can use Math.round(value * 100) + '%' on formatters to solve problems with the 0.57 and other values

Comment: I prefere `Number.toFixed()` :)

Comment: new Number(value*100).toFixed() ... hm excellent, and works too with 0.57 and others. I didn't use Number before